# When syncing, removed contacts still show up (One contacts)

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, contacts

I just tried out using the Ubuntu One Contacts app for Android. First I imported all the contacts from my phone, SIM-card and Google mail account, then I spent quite a while removing duplicates which got imported. Then I tried to sync it for the first time.

The strange thing is that I also got all the contacts which I removed from my contacts list on the website. So I have to set "show only contacts with phone numbers" to get all the email addresses I imported from Google earlier to not show up, even though I deleted them from the contacts list and have only Ubuntu One contacts showing.

Why is that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guess it was just a sync problem since this got sorted out later on...